# Returning String without Whitespace from Velocity Macro (Velocimacros)

Tags: velocity

I am new to using **Apache Velocity**. What is the correct way of returning a string from a Macro or a Velocimacro?

Since I did not have a clue on how to return a string from a Macro, I decided to do something like

```
#macro(query_url $query_param)
     q=$query_param
 #end
```

I can then call the Macro using: `#query_url("*")`

The problem with this is that the resulting value contains a Tab or number of Spaces before the 'q=' when I call it. One option is to delete the spaces like:

```
#macro(query_url $query_param)q=$query_param#end
```

This fixes my problem but is very hard to read.  To take this a step further consider:

```
#macro(default_query_url)
    #if($request.params.get('q'))
        #query_url($request.params.get('q'))
    #else
        #query_url("*")
     #end
 #end
```

Vs.

```
#macro(default_query_url)
#if($request.params.get('q'))#query_url($request.params.get('q'))#else#query_url("*")#end
#end
```

In the second case there is no whitespace, but editing it would be very difficult for more complicated macros.

I am curious what is the correct way to return values from **Velocimacros** and if I can **Trim** the resulting **Whitespace** before returning it?